# Meaning of これ、聞いたほうがいいのかな?

Tags: meaning

んー…別に寝不足って訳じゃないんだけど。ちょっと、やな夢見てさ…

…やな夢？

ん…昔のね……

え、えぇと…

あ、あ、えっと、これ…聞いた方が良いのかな？それとも聞かない方が……

My question is about what the これ refers to. I think it's like "これを聞いたほうがいいのかな" where they are wondering whether it's a good idea to ask about this(これreferring to questions and details they want to know about this dream). Or does it refer to something else?

edit: Another potential meaning I can think of is これ meaning こういう場合

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「これ」, in this context, would refer to the question(s) itself/themselves that the speaker has in mind and is about to ask the other person.  In other words, we as readers do not know what it is about at this point.

Unlike 「それ」, which is used to refer to something that has already been explicitly mentioned, 「これ」 is often used to refer to something that has not been mentioned.

It is like saying in English, "I wonder if I should ask **this** or not."

"これ meaning こういう場合{ばあい}" is a very educated guess and is even pretty close, but it would be more natural to think it would refer to the actual question(s) that is/are about to be revealed